# c++ fixed size multidimensional array

Tags: c++

I first thought of the idea when looking at c style multidimensional arrays and realized that there is not really a modern c++ version of that.other than having an std::array of std::array which is not very convenient, so I decided to essentially make a copy of std::array and modify it so would act like a multidimensional array. here is the code

array.h

```
#pragma once
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <limits>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

namespace turtle {
    template<typename T, typename Dim, bool opt = false>
    class array;
    template<typename T, template<size_t, size_t...> typename dim,size_t Size, size_t... Sizes, bool opt>
#if __cplusplus > 201709L
    requires (Size != 0) && ((Sizes != 0) && ... && true) //prevent any size parameters from being zero
#endif
        class array<T,dim<Size,Sizes...>,opt> {
            template<typename ... Args>
            static constexpr auto multply(const Args& ... args) { return (args * ...); }
            constexpr static size_t size_ = multply(Size,Sizes...);
        public:
            using value_type = T;
            using size_type = size_t;
            using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
            using pointer = T*;
            using const_pointer = const T*;
            using reference = T&;
            using const_reference = const T&;

            using iterator = T*;
            using const_iterator = const T*;
            template<typename... Args>
            array(const Args&... args) {
                array_copy(sizeof...(args)-1,args...);
            }
            array() = default;
            ~array() = default;
            //Element access
            constexpr reference at(size_type pos) { return data_[pos]; }
            constexpr const_reference at(size_type pos) const { return data_[pos]; }
            constexpr decltype(auto) operator[](const size_type& pos) {
                if constexpr (sizeof...(Sizes)) {
                    auto temp = array<T, dim<Sizes...>,true>();
                    temp.data_ = data_ + multply(pos, Sizes...);
                    return temp;
                }
                else {
                    return data_at(pos);
                }
            }
            constexpr const auto& operator[](const size_type& pos) const { return (*this)[pos]; }
            template<typename Index, typename ... Indices>
            constexpr reference operator ()(const Index& index, const Indices& ... indices) {
                return data_[this->index(index, indices...)];
            }
            template<typename Index, typename ... Indices>
            constexpr const_reference operator()(const Index& index, const Indices& ... indices) const {
                return (*this)(index,indices...);
            }
            template<typename Index, typename ... Indices>
            constexpr size_type index(const Index& index, const Indices& ... indices) {
                static_assert (sizeof...(Indices) >= sizeof...(Sizes), "not enough parameters");
                static_assert (sizeof...(Indices) <= sizeof...(Sizes), "too many parameters");
                //x + (y*i) + (z*i*j) + (w*i*j*k) ...
                return get_index(std::pair<size_type, size_type>(Size, index), std::pair<size_type, size_type>(Sizes, indices)...);
            }
            constexpr reference front() { return data_[0]; }
            constexpr const_reference front() const { return front(); }
            constexpr reference back() { return data_[size_ - 1]; }
            constexpr const_reference back() const { return back(); }
            constexpr T* data() noexcept { return data_; }
            constexpr const T* data() const noexcept { return data(); }
            //Iterators
            constexpr iterator begin() noexcept { return data_; }
            constexpr iterator end() noexcept { return begin() + size_; }
            constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return data_; }
            constexpr const_iterator end() const noexcept { return begin() + size_; }
            constexpr iterator cbegin() const noexcept { return begin(); }
            constexpr iterator cend() const noexcept { return begin() + size_; }
            //Capacity
            constexpr size_type size() const noexcept { return size_; }
            constexpr bool empty() const noexcept { return begin() == end(); }
            constexpr size_type max_size() const noexcept { return std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() / sizeof(T); }
            //Operations
            constexpr void fill(const T& value) {
                std::fill(begin(), end(), value);
            }
            constexpr void swap(array other)  noexcept(noexcept(std::swap(std::declval<value_type&>(), std::declval<value_type&>()))) {
                /*from swap_ranges*/
                iterator first1 = data();
                iterator first2 = other.data();
                while (first1 != end()) {
                    std::swap(*first1, *first2);
                    ++first1; ++first2;
                }
            }
            T data_array[opt ? 1 : size_];
            T* data_ = data_array;
        private:
            //Helper functions
            template<typename Index, typename ... Indices>
            constexpr size_type get_index(const Index& index, const Indices& ... indices) const {
                size_type new_index = index.second;
                size_type final_index = 0;
                if constexpr (sizeof...(Indices)) {
                    new_index *= multply(indices.first...);
                    return get_index(indices...) + new_index;
                }
                return final_index + new_index;
            }
            template<typename Arg,typename... Args>
            constexpr void array_copy(const size_type& size,const Arg& arg, const Args&... args) {
                static_assert(sizeof...(args) < size_, "Too many parameters");
                data_[size-sizeof...(args)] = arg;
                if constexpr (sizeof...(args) > 0) {
                    array_copy(size,args...);
                }
            }
            constexpr reference data_at(const size_type& pos) { return data_[pos]; }
    };

    //Comparisons
    template<typename T, template<size_t, size_t...> typename dim, size_t Size, size_t... Sizes>
    constexpr inline bool operator==(const array<T,dim<Size,Sizes...>>& one, const array<T,dim<Size,Sizes...>>& two) {
        auto first1 = one.begin(), first2 = two.begin();
        for (; first1 != one.end(); first1++, first2++) {
            if (*first1 != *first2) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
} //namespace turtle
template<size_t, size_t...>
struct Size;
```

here is a test case

```
#include <iostream>
#include "array.h"

int main() {
    turtle::array<int,Size<10,10,10>> array;

    for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i) {
        array.at(i) = i;
    }

    array[9][9][9] = -1;

    for(const auto& item : array) {
        std::cout << item << '\n';
    }
    return  0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code test cases that show how to use this library.

Comment: Ok I added a test case